assign SD card pins used by HPS for FPGA DE1-soc
I am following a tutorial and making some changes to it. thi sproject uses Nios2 and the goal is to use the SD card slot from the DE1-soc board and read a bmp image file from the sd card and send it to the screen using vga port. I have used Qsys to connect all my module such as the SD card interface, Plls, etc. Now I need to assign pins using the Pin Planner from the Quartus (I'm using Quartus 17 since it's the only existing version that supports SD card interface IP). The SD card peripheral is part of the HPS fabric but from the many tutorials that I have seen I am assuming it it possible to access it with the FPGA as well but I don't know how.
I have looked into the DE1-soc user manual and found these pins for the SD card:
Pin Assignment of the micro SD card socket
First noticable thing is the output signals from the SD card interface IP are different from the signals in the manual
SD card interface output signals. You can also see the pins that the fitter has suggested which I don't think are correct.
The pins that are mentioned in the manual for the micro SD card are reserved for HPS and are not accessible to assign in the pin planner. This is the error I get:
Error pin assignment
Do I need to also add an HPS IP in my Qsys design? I am skeptical about that because I have not seen people using that IP in the tutorials. How can I solve this issue? what are the correct pins to be assigned for these SD card signals?
Good to mention:
this is the main tutorial I was following:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/content-details/649126/design-a-qsys-system-using-the-nios-ii-processor-sd-card-interface.html

You need to add new SD card slot. Yes, one extra, because the existing SD slot is dedicated to HPS, the linux is running from it, and you really don't want to mess with loan i/o, recompiling U-Boot and preloader, finding the right version of the bootloader that has features matching the linux kernel version to be used, editing device trees, etc.
Just use some SD card breakout board, plug it to one of GPIO connectors, and create matching pin assignments.
ps: The image showing some SD card pins - it can't be from the DE1-SoC manual. It looks like it's a screenshot from the pin planner using project unrelated to DE1-SoC, as the pin assignment for that SD interface is clashing with DE1-SoC SDRAM pins.
